# How to get value inside '[]' using regex?

Tags: regex, regex-group

**Hi, I have written regex. in here i want select only value insdie **

> [buttonRouter, CheckBoxModule, RadioButtonModule, DropDownButtonModule, SplitButtonModule, SwitchModule, SharedModule, ProgressButtonModule]

**Instead of this it select**

> imports: [buttonRouter, CheckBoxModule, RadioButtonModule, DropDownButtonModule, SplitButtonModule, SwitchModule, SharedModule, ProgressButtonModule]

[image: my requirement]

My requirement, regex has to select  values only inside **imports: [value]**

Comment: What is the language you are going to use it in? JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should return only return the value part but still look for "imports: ":

`(?<!:imports: )\[.+\]`

Comment: working fine thanks